# Bounding function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, differential, stability-in-odes

I am trying to work on a function of the form $\frac{x^{2}}{(x+y)^{2}}$ near the origin, however the limit of this function is indeterminate. Is anyone aware of any function which bounds this above for $x,y\geq 0$? This is in relation to steady state equilbria stability in a system of ODE's.

Comment: If $\;x,y\ge0\;$ then $\;x+y\ge x\;$ , and thus $\;\cfrac{x^2}{(x+y)^2}\le\cfrac{x^2}{x^2}=1\;$ ...